# MSGraph API filtering users returns BadRequest

Tags: c#, api, microsoft-graph-api

I have the following code:

```
 IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .Build();
        ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(app);
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

        var users = await graphClient
            .Users
            .Request()
            .Filter("eq(mail, 'someEntity@mycompany.com')")
            .GetAsync();
```

The above throws the following exception:

Code: BadRequest

Message: Invalid filter clause

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should filter be ---> `.Filter("mail eq 'someEntity@mycompany.com'")`

Comment: I've posed as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per OData URI convention (read [here](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/)), the filter `eq` should be defined as `propertyName eq PropertyValue`.

So update the filter as

```
.Filter("mail eq 'someEntity@mycompany.com'")
```